# Mutating Arrays Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

The following mutation does not work:

```
const mutations = {
  [types.UPDATE_IMG_URLS] (state, newArray) {
    state.imageUrlArray.concat(newArray)
  },
(...)
}
```

However this one does:

```
const mutations = {
  [types.UPDATE_IMG_URLS] (state, newArray) {
    state.imageUrlArray = state.imageUrlArray.concat(newArray)
  },
(...)
}
```

I thought arrays and objects were passed by reference in Javascript. Does Vuex meddle with this behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `concat` method does not change the existing array, but returns a new array. That's why you need to actively overwrite `state.imageUrlArray` with the freshly returned array.

If, for some reason, you want to make the mutation in place, you should be able to to this: `state.imageUrlArray(state.imageUrlArray, newArray)`

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat for more details.